# Large memory block allocation and 4K blocks

Tags: windows, memory, virtual, internals, win64

Consider this quote from Mark Russiniovich's books on Windows internals. This is about large-page allocation mechanism, intended for allocating large non-paged memory blocks in physical memory

http://books.google.com/books?id=CdxMRjJksScC&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194#v=onepage

> Attempts to allocate large pages may fail after the operating system
>   has been running for an extended period, because the physical memory
>   for each large page must occupy a significant number (see Table 10-1)
>   of physically contiguous small pages, and this extent of physical
>   pages must furthermore begin on a large page boundary. (For example,
>   physical pages 0 through 511 could be used as a large page on an x64
>   system, as could physical pages 512 through 1,023, but pages 10
>   through 521 could not.) Free physical memory does become fragmented as
>   the system runs. This is not a problem for allocations using small
>   pages but can cause large page allocations to fail.

If I understand this correctly, he's saying that fragmentation produced by scattered 4K pages can prevent successful allocation of large 2M pages in *physical memory*. But why? Ordinary 4K physical pages are easily relocatable and can also be easily swapped out. In other words, if we have a physical memory region not occupied by other 2M pages, we can always "clean it up": make it available by relocating any interfering 4K pages from that physical memory region to some other location. I.e. from the "naive" point of view, 2M allocations should "always succeed", as long as we have enough free physical RAM.

What is wrong with my logic? What exactly is Mark talking about when he says that physical memory fragmentation caused by 4K pages can prevent successful allocation of large pages?

Comment: Relocating an allocated physical memory brings overhead for the system. Also finding the most unfragmented contiguous memory space requires another overhead. This may be the cause?

Comment: It seems to me that he explained it clearly. You are bringing in techniques to solve the problem, which Windows might be using in newer versions, but probably didn't have when he wrote the book.

Comment: I don't believe we can answer "What is wrong with the logic" when there is nothing wrong with the logic.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: Firstly, the ability to freely manipulate physical pages in transparent (to running processes) fashion is the fundamental property of virtual memory. This is what virtual memory is. I don't see how it could possibly be unavailable to those versions of Windows. Secondly, by "that logic" I mean my logic, not the Russinovich's one.

Comment: Applications and drivers can lock/allocate physical memory. Given that, is your question why cant the OS move the pages of allocated physical memory?

Comment: @josh poley: Drivers allocate RAM in system non-paged pool of pre-determined size reserved at system startup. These pages, if I understand it correctly, will not be randomly scattered across RAM. Applications can allocate non-paged memory in several ways. Large pages (the topic of this question) are non-paged, but they are accessed through virtual address space of the process, meaning that they can easily be moved to a different location in RAM.

Comment: My question is: what kind of 4K pages Mark is talking about? If these are some exotic/special/locked/non-relocatable pages, then why Mark isn't saying it explicitly? If these are "regular" 4K pages, then why Mark is ignoring the fact that system can easily relocate these pages?

Comment: @AndreyT, Both user mode applications and drivers can ensure that pages are resident in physical memory (eg [AllocateUserPhysicalPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366528.aspx), see also the `Locking Memory` section on pg 199). A page that is guaranteed to be available without a page fault isn't easily moved.

Comment: @josh poley: AFAIK, "locked" memory in Windows is simply considered an unconditional part of process working set. Which means that (despite a popular belief) not only it can be relocated in RAM, it can actually be swapped out to disk (!) when the process is not running. I know about `AllocateUserPhysicalPages`, which is a different story. And it is quite an exotic thing, which I believe would be mentioned by Mark if that was what he meant. To me it looks like Mark is talking about "regular" 4K pages.

Comment: Check out the docs for [VirtualLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895.aspx), couple of relevant sentences: "Locks the specified region of the process's virtual address space into physical memory, ensuring that subsequent access to the region will not incur a page fault... These pages are guaranteed not to be written to the pagefile while they are locked."

Comment: @josh poley: Well, I believe it has been postulated that MS `VirtualLock` documentation makes bogus promises. See here for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/06/5924058.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually worked this way in Windows XP.  But the cost was too prohibitive and a design change in Vista disabled this approach.  Explained well in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/28/10121300.aspx?Redirected=true), I'll quote the essential part:

> In Windows Vista, the memory manager folks recognized that these long delays made very large pages less attractive for applications, so they changed the behavior so requests for very large pages from applications went through the "easy parts" of looking for contiguous physical memory, but gave up before the memory manager went into desperation mode, preferring instead just to fail.

Comment: I see. The logic behind the decision to change the behavior is not clear to me though. The suggestion that switching from "long delays" to "failures" can make large pages more "attractive to applications" (???) makes no sense to me whatsoever. The current recommendation is to allocate large pages early, when memory fragmentation is still low, but this recommendation applies equally to the old and to the new allocation algorithm.

Comment: I.e. with the same degree of success they could've said that in order to avoid those "long delays" one has to allocate large pages early. Basically, I'd go as far as to conclude that the rationale given in the blog post is typical bogus "marketing speak". I'd guess that the original, more complicated allocation mechanism required support/maintenance effort, which was deemed excessive for such a rarely used "niche" feature.

Comment: Maybe that's the liability of using somebody else's words.  The way I'd put it: "it sucked.  The worse-case behavior was dreadful with no reasonable way for the app to predict how bad it could be.  So they just removed it".

Answer (score 2):

He's talking about a specific problem that exists with allocating and freeing contiguous memory blocks over time, and you're describing a solution. Nothing is wrong with your logic and that's roughly what the .NET Garbage Collector does to reduce memory fragmentation. You're spot on.

If you have 10 seats per row at a baseball game and seats 2, 4, 6, and 8 are taken (**fragmented**), you will never be able to get 3 seats in that row for you and your friends unless you ask someone to move (**compacted**).

There's nothing special about the 4k blocks he's describing.